# GtkEntry & button-press-event

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I need to use `button-press-event` signal in GtkEntry. All works great, but when the `sensitive` property (in the GtkEntry) is set to FALSE this signal does not emit. Is there way to emit `button-press-event` with `sensitive=FALSE` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. [This page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--sensitive) explicitly states that the `sensitive` property set to FALSE disables all input. This means you can't get a `button-press-event` when `sensitive` is set to FALSE, since it disables this signal. Any reason why you would want to disable it and still try to use it?

Comment: Thank you! I think I should change application